# Vim: disable word wrapping for specific lines

Tags: vim, line-breaks, word-wrap, text-width

I am using `:set textwidth=80` to make the Vim editor do hard wrapping automatically. However, sometimes for certain lines within a file (e.g. tables in LaTeX), I do not want Vim to do any hard wrapping automatically. Is there a way to mark certain lines to disable hard wrapping in Vim? Or automatically `:set textwidth=0` just for specified lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing out-of-the-box, but you can build a solution with an `:autocmd <buffer>` on the `CursorMoved,CursorMovedI` events. On each move of the cursor, you have to check whether you're currently in one of those "certain lines", and modify the local `'textwidth'` option accordingly:

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI <buffer> if IsSpecialLine() | setlocal textwidth=0 | else | setlocal textwidth=80 | endif
```

Put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/tex.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType tex autocmd ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

For the `IsSpecialLine()` function, you probably need to match a regular expression on the current line (`getline('.') =~# "..."`). If you can identify the "certain lines" through syntax highlighting, my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) can do all the work for you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `IsSpecialLine()` function? For example, the line contains `&` without a leading `\ `(i.e. contains `&` but not `\&`). Thank you very much!

Comment: In that case, the body inside that function would be `return getline('.') =~# '\\\@<!&'`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried [Ingo Karkat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208698/1860757). Although it does work very well and does what the OP asks, I find it distracting (if I have long tables with row hundreds of characters long, there are a lot of shifts up and down when passing over tables) and can slow down a lot vim on big files (the `textwidth` and `wrap` are changed for the **whole** file, so running the `autocmd` for every cursor movement can be costly).

So I propose a *static* solution based on the idea that *hopefully* you have to modify a table as few times as possible. I've added the following to my `ftplugin/tex.vim` file:

```
" By default the text is 
let s:textwidth = 90
let &l:textwidth=s:textwidth

" Toggle between "textwidth and wrap" and "textwidth=0 and nowrap".
" When editing a table, can be useful to have all the '&' aligned (using e.g.
" ':Tabularize /&') but without line brakes and wraps. Besides it's very
" annoying when line brakes "happen" while editing.
" As hopefully tables must be edited only from time to time, one can toggle
" wrap and textwidth by hand. 
function! ToggleTwWrap() "{{{
  " if textwidth and wrap is used, then disable them
  if &textwidth > 0 
    let &l:textwidth=0
    setlocal nowrap
  else " otherwise re-enable them
    let &l:textwidth=s:textwidth
    setlocal wrap
  endif
endfunction
```

So now if I want to edit manually a table I simply do

```
:call ToggleTwWrap()
```

to disable wrapping and textwidth and then again when I'm done with the table.

And of course you can create a command or a map

Comment: This is a really nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly set it for specific file types, but I don't think you can change those settings (or any, really) for individual lines.

Comment: I do have individual `textwidth` settings for different file types. I really like to hard wrap LaTeX source text for easy reading. However, it really messes up the source text of my tables. I really just want to disable hard wrapping for LaTeX tables code.

Answer (score 0):

Ingo Karat's answer works but setting textwidth on *every single cursor move* is too slow. This adapted version will only call `setlocal textwidth=` if the text width is actually going to change. This speeds things up considerably:

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI <buffer> if IsSpecialLine() | if &textwidth != 0 | setlocal textwidth=0 | endif | else | if &textwidth != 80 | setlocal textwidth=80 | endif | endif
```